Decomposition of stock returns with leverage
I came across this question in Kopp's portfolio management and risk, where we are told, that a stock is bought at S(0) with leverage - a mixture of $wS(0)$ cash and $(1-w)S(0)$ loan and told to prove that the return on the leveraged position $R_{l}$ is $r + \frac{1}{w}(R_{S} - r)$ where $R_s$ is the return on the stock, $w\in(1,0)$ and where $r$ is the risk free rate.
This implies that $R_{S} = wR_{l} + (1-w)r$ - so the stock returns are decomposed into the return on the leveraged position and another component.

I am unable to derive the relationship. My initial thought was to look at the initial cost of setting up the portfolio, which is $S(0)$, and note that at any subsequent point the portfolio value is a combination of the final stock price $S(1)$ (say) and the loan $-(1+r)(1-w)S(0)$. However this does not simplify to give what I need as in particular I don't have an expression for $S(1)$.

I can't fully understand the expression we are meant to prove - $R_{S} = wR_{l} + (1-w)r$. Does this mean if we use leverage to buy a stock the stock return is simply a proportion of the leveraged position and some asset growing at a risk free rate? But both these terms are deterministic? Have I misunderstood what they mean by leverage?



I guess the convention is gross returns, would you expand on this? In which case $\frac{\Pi_1}{wS_0}=\frac{S_0R_S-(1-w)S_0r}{wS_0}=\frac{1}{w}(R_S-r)+r$, where $\Pi_1$ is the time $1$ value of the leveraged portfolio and $wS_0$ the unleveraged cash investment at time $0$.

@Snoop Yes, believe its for gross returns.  All the terms make sense to me except for the $(1-w)S_{0}r$ term - shouldn't this be $wS_{0}r$ i.e- the final leveraged value is the total stock return component minus the cash component which has weight w, and rate of return $r$, so $wS_{0}r$?

At time $0$ a loan is taken out of amount $(1-w)S_0$. At time $1$ the amount due is $(1-w)S_0r$ (following the gross returns convention). Thus the cash value of closing the portfolio position at time $1$ would be (a) cashing out the stock ($+S_0R_S$) and (b) repaying the loan ($-(1-w)S_0r$).

@Snoop Thanks! This makes sense - appreciate the clarification. Happy to accept this as the answer if you want to add it as such!

By following the convention of gross returns over a single period, the time $t=1$ value of the stock is $S_1=S_0R_S$ and the time $t=1$ amount due of the loan is $(1-w)S_0r,\,w \in (0,1)$. Therefore, the cash value of the leveraged strategy liquidated at time $t=1$ is given by $S_1-(1-w)S_0r$, where $+S_1$ is the cash inflow obtained by selling the stock, while $-(1-w)S_0r$ is the cash outflow for repaying the loan. So the return on the unleveraged initial cash investment $wS_0$ is given by
$$\frac{S_1-(1-w)S_0r}{wS_0}=\frac{S_0R_S-(1-w)S_0r}{wS_0}=\frac{1}{w}(R_S-r)+r,\,\quad w \in (0,1)$$
as claimed.
